# In tomcat what happens when session.invalidate() is called

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

when a user logsout we are doing a session.invalidate().

But is it possible that if sesions are persisted by tomcat, which it does by default, and if the same user tries to access the webapp in a shortwhile, the same persisted session is restored and reused??

does tomcat invalidate session during reload or restart of application?... does the "saveOnRestart" configuration in server.xml completely control this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the same user tries to access the app a new session id is generated for him and so he can't access anything from the previous session (even if it hasn't been deleted yet, but it is likely to be deleted). The implementation details don't matter here - the point is that when the session expires or is invalidated, all the session-data is lost.

Comment: Thanks Bozho, that is my expectation as well... I guess more direct question would be, does tomcat invalidate session during reload or restart of application... does the "saveOnRestart" configuration in server.xml completely control this?

Comment: It seems that tomcat does not invalidate sessions by itself during reload/restart instead persists them (based on configurations like "saveOnRestart")...